# Laravel Eloquent Relation between 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need some help make a music library database.
I have 3 tables *albums*, *artists*, *roles*
I want an artist to have a role for each album.
like :
artist 1 work as Composer for album 1, but also work as arranger on album 2 or work as composer and arranger on album 3

I have tried this
[image: database design]

how should database looks? and what type relationship is?

Answer (score 2):

In your current schema, you will not be able to tag the role of the artist on basis of album. 
As there is no relation in your tables to define that the entry in `artist_role` table is for specific album. So, what I would suggest is to create an intermediate table containing the **`role_id`**,**`artist_id`** and **`album_id`**.
To use this intermediate table with laravel's `manyToMany` relationship, you can define the methods in your models specifying one attribute as pivot attribute.

For, e.g. in **Artist Model**:

```
public function Roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles')->withPivot('album_id');
}

public function Albums(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Albums')->withPivot('role_id');
}
```

Define similar methods for other Models also..

### Update:

For getting `Artist` with its role in Album add following method in the `Album` model:

```
public function Artists(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artist')->withPivot('role_id');
}
```

For roles add following method:

```
public function Roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles')->withPivot('artist_id');
}
```

Comment: how to get roles value in blade?

Comment: if you mean role name, you can do something like `Role::find($role_id)->get()->value('name')`, or you can use `join` to get the role names in the same query

Comment: Sorry, I mean get artist role for the current album